# Write out name and value from dictionary

Tags: javascript

This is trivial I know but I'm so used to OOP languages.  I'm trying to figure out how to write out each name/value in either one alert or many, just so I can verify the data

```
var dCookieNameValuePairs = {};

for (i = 0; i < cookieValues.length; i++)
{
    var akeyValuePair = aCookieValues[i].split("=");
    dCookieNameValuePairs[keyValuePair[0]] = keyValuePair[1];
}

// display each name value pair testing
for (i = 0; i < dCookieNameValuePairs.length; i++)
{
    alert("Name: " + dCookieNameValuePairs[] + "Value: " + 
}
```

I'm stuck at the second for loop...I am not sure how to iterate through the dictionary and then focus on each name/value to spit it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use **`for..in`** for enumerating through a dictionary/map.

```
for ( var prop in dCookieNameValuePairs ) {
   if ( dCookieNameValuePairs.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
       alert( dCookieNameValuePairs[prop] )
   }
}
```

I may have typo'd. Only use `.length` when you are dealing with an array `[]` or a custom array-like object that you defined to have `.length` populated.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't use much JS so really never used a for loop in JS yet.  Makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i in dCookieNameValuePairs) {
    alert("Name: " + i + " Value: " + dCookieValuePairs[i]);
}
```

See the "JavaScript Does Not Support Associative Arrays" section of [this page](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays) for more details.

If you don't need an associative array, you might put the keys and values into an array of objects instead. So your first loop would look something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < cookieValues.length; i++) {
    var akeyValuePair = cookieValues[i].split("=");
    dCookieNameValuePairs.push({key: akeyValuePair[0], value: akeyValuePair[1]});
}
```